# Pandas `to_latex`: how to format multi-index tables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

## Question

I am trying to format the `to_latex` output of a Pandas table, which is the result of a `pivot_table` operation. My question is: How do I pass formatters to the `to_latex` method in this case?

### Example

More specifically, consider this example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo","bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two","one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small","small", "large", "small","small","large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D','E'], index=['A'], columns=['C','B'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

The output is

```
    D                E
C   large   small   large   small
B   one     two     one     two     one     two     one     two
A                               
bar     4.0     7.0     5.0     6.0     6.0     9.0     8.0     9.0
foo     4.0     NaN     1.0     6.0     9.0     NaN     2.0     11.0
```

### My attempt

Here I try to format the columns `large` and `small` differently.

```
    def f2(x):
        return f"%.{2}f" % x
    def f5(x):
        return f"%.{5}f" % x
    
    formatters = {'large':f2,'small':f5}
    table.to_latex('tables/tab.tex',formatters=formatters,longtable=True)
```

But the resulting table is not formatted appropriately. My guess is that it has to do with the layered nature of this table. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo","bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two","one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small","small", "large", "small","small","large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D','E'], index=['A'], columns=['C','B'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()

def f2(x):
        return f"%.{2}f" % x

def f5(x):
    return f"%.{5}f" % x

formatters = {'large':f2,'small':f5}

table.to_latex('tables/tab.tex',formatters=formatters,longtable=True)
```